# How to get information from my SQL Databse

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I try to get the `destination(zielort)` for the `artikelID` which I will get from my GUI. Unfortunately, I always get the error message

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column
>   'id' in 'where clause'

In my Database is an ArtikelID with ID=1234. In my test class I try to get the `destination(zielort)` of my `ArtikelID` 1234. As a result, I should get `E1.R10.D2,` but I get the error message.

I hope u can help me to find my mistake.

```
**Test Class:**
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //DBConnect connect = new DBConnect();
        //String s = connect.getLoginDaten(1);
        //System.out.print(s);


    DBConnect connect = new DBConnect();
    String s= connect.getZielort(1234);
    System.out.print(s);
}


**DB-Connect Class:**
public String getZielort(int arikel_ID) {
        String zielort="";
        try {
            String query = "select zielort from warenliste where id="+arikel_ID;
            rs= st.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                zielort = rs.getString("zielort");  
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return zielort;
    }

    public int getArtikel(int arikel_ID) {
        int artikelid=0;
        try {
            String query = "select Artikel_ID from warenliste where id="+arikel_ID;
            rs= st.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                artikelid = rs.getInt("Artikel_ID");    
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return artikelid;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception means that your table doesn't have a column named `id`. From your query

```
"select Artikel_ID from warenliste where id="+arikel_ID;
```

I infer that that the column is called `Artikel_ID`, so your query should look like this:

```
"select Artikel_ID from warenliste where Artikel_ID="+arikel_ID;
```

Of course, you may have a different schema. Take a look into your database to see how the columns of the table `warenliste` are named and then replace `Artikel_ID` with the actual column name.

By the way, if you are working with user input, take a look at [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for security reasons (like SQL injection).

Comment: for security reasons you even should not use the MySQL username and password, hardcoded in Java which can be very eazy decompiled.. But you should need to use a gateway with sockets or webservice access with REST/SOAP/XML or JSON RPC/GrapQL protocols ...